# is it possible to use dotnet command line tool to upgrade dependencies inside a Directory.Build.props file?

Tags: .net

I adopted the approach of having one Directory.Build.props file in the root directory of my workspace to centralize the common dependencies shared by many projects.
However, dotnet tool doesn't seem to understand this file and cannot edit it to add or upgrade dependencies.

I tried these command variations to add a package with no success:

```
dotnet add package Sms --version 2.5.6
#  got:
#    Could not find any project in `/home...

dotnet add Directory.Build.props package Sms --version 2.5.6
#  got:
#    error MSB4057: The target "GenerateRestoreGraphFile" does not exist in the project.
#    Unable to create dependency graph file for project 'Directory.Build.props'.
#    Cannot add package reference.
```

To solve the problem i'm editing the Directory.Build.props manually, which is not ideal since i have to manually search for package versions throughout the nuget website.

So, my question is...
Is it possible to use dotnet command line tool to upgrade dependencies inside a Directory.Build.props file somehow? Or it wasn't make for that?

Here is a sample of the Directory.Build.props file:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.117" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.30.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Interactive.Async" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Async" Version="6.0.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Markdig" Version="0.31.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.6.2" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeKit" Version="4.0.0" />

    <!-- Utilitários para processamento de strings, como capitalização e hifenização -->
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer.Core" Version="2.14.1" />

    <!-- Referências para empacotamento e distribuição do aplicativo. -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Packaging.Targets">
      <Version>0.1.220-*</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNet.Glob" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetZip" Version="1.16.0" />

  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```